# Soil type info from grib file

Tags: netcdf, grib

I want to read soil type info from grib file, but dont know a variable name.
I expect that this variable contains a value between 1 and 9, corresponding to the possible different types of soil for each grid point.

I'm use NetcdfFile library but I can not find the variable.

Any suggestion?